# How to continuous reading resources(configs) by spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, io, spark-streaming

The back ground is that we need to read file which is used as global configs to do data calculation and the file will be changed each hour, so it is necessary to reload the file. our confusion is about how to reload the config if the 'for-loop' goes to the end and how to notify the main process that file is changing, if spark engine could complete it independently?  Sample codes like that:

```
// init streamingContext
val alertConfigRDD: RDD[String] = sc.textFile("alert-config.json")
val alertConfig = alertConfigRDD.collect()
for (config <- alertConfigs) {
  // spark streaming process: select window duration according to config details.
}
streamingContext.start()
streamingContext.awaitTermination()
```

Thanks for solutions in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If it's vital to have this resource being updated for data processing then load if from one place (being it HDFS, S3 or any other storage accessible from all executors) on each batch before actual processing.